# Does watching pornography increase sexual performance in women?

Tags: physiology, sexuality, gender, pornography

I am referring to these lines:

> A recent study reported that **increasing porn use** is linked to
> decreased sexual performance in men and **increased sexual performance
> in women**.

[Big Think - Is watching pornography bad for men — but good for women?](https://bigthink.com/health/is-watching-pornography-bad-for-men-but-good-for-women/)

> The researchers found that **more frequent porn use** was associated with
> lower sexual performance for men but **higher sexual performance for
> women**.

[PsyPost - Porn use linked to lower sexual performance for men – but higher sexual performance for women, study finds](https://www.psypost.org/2022/05/porn-use-linked-to-lower-sexual-performance-for-men-but-higher-sexual-performance-for-women-study-finds-63059)

This question is about [Pornography and the male libido](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/pornography-and-the-male-libido) so I am asking about women.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The relevant research paper doesn't address the question as to whether or not pornography increases sexual performance in women.  Sommet and Berent (2022) found a *correlation*:

> In contrast, **among women, higher and increasing frequencies of porn use were associated with *higher* levels of sexual self-competence, improved sexual functioning, and enhanced partner-reported sexual satisfaction** (for some aspects).
> <sub>[*Porn use and men’s and women’s sexual performance: evidence from a large longitudinal sample*](https://doi.org/10.1017/S003329172100516X); see also [this survey data](https://osf.io/nfbcp/).</sub>

The paper doesn't claim that porn does (or doesn't) improve women's sexual performance.  In fact, they spend a paragraph warning the reader about the correlation vs. causation problem:

> Third, **observational data cannot be used to draw causal inferences**. However, we believe that causality should be assessed in
> terms of a ‘continuum of plausibility’ (Dunning, 2008) along
> which longitudinal evidence is located above cross-sectional evidence (but below experimental evidence; see also Grosz, Rohrer,
> & Thoemmes, 2020). In our case, given the consistencies between
> the results from the fixed-effects (focusing on within-participants
> change) and first-difference (focused on wave-to-wave change)
> regressions, we believe that causality is at least plausible. That
> being said, **two alternative explanations – which we regard as
> less parsimonious in the case of a reversed interaction (for a
> related discussion, see Wright, 2021b) – cannot be formally
> excluded: (i) the presence of unobserved time-varying confounders (e.g. variations in well-being; see Kohut & Štulhofer, 2018)
> and (ii) reciprocal effects (e.g. for men, a decrease in sexual self-competence can cause an increase in porn use, and for women,
> the reverse could be true)**.